# portability of DLL with CUDA code

Tags: cuda

I have DLL, which contain CUDA function (image processing). This DLL is compiled with VISUAL STUDIO 2008 Express edition. I call this DLL with LabVIEW.

This DLL and LabVIEW VI are developed on one computer (office) and I need to run same program in differen computer (in lab).

Q1: Do I have to instal cuda toolkit or cuda SDK on computer in lab?
Q2: Do I have to recompile DLL on computer in lab or DLL are completly portable?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Yes, you have to install CUDA toolkit and SDK if you use any functions/ wrappers ( like `cudaSafeCall`) from SDK. In general SDK is not nesessary. You need in compatible NVIDIA GPU driver instaled on Lab computer, too.
2. You need not recompile if Lab computer and your own have the same Microsoft Visual Studio runtime, CUDA runtime version and Lab computer have GPU device with proper compute capability that your code was compiled for. For more information about CUDA code compatibility see 3.1.2 - 3.1.4 sections in CUDA C programming Guide.